# Windows 8 sound dissapearing

Tags: windows-8, audio, m-audio

I have a problem with playing audio on windows 8.

After some time when I turn on my pc and listen to a music and set playback on pause and turn it on after ~5 min then sound stops playing. It can be youtube flash player, foobar2000 or VLC player whatever.

But if I restart my windows-audio services by command line commands:

```
net stop "Audiosrv"
net stop "AudioEndpointBuilder"
net start "AudioEndpointBuilder"
net start "Audiosrv"
```

then the audio starts playing again normally.

I have a Reaper DAW installed and it plays sound normally (via ASIO driver) even the sound is dissapeared in other programs which are using windows audio.

Also, if I use "Line 1/2 (M-Audio Delta AP 192)" playback audio device in foobar2000 and sound dissapeared and I switch playback audio device to "S/PDIF (M-Audio Delta AP 192)" then the sound starts playing again normally in foobar2000 via this new selected device "S/PDIF (M-Audio Delta AP 192)".

I have:

```
Windows 8 professional x64
Sound card: m-audio audiophile 192 (driver: Delta Series Driver 6.0.8 (latest))
Bios have the latest firmware.
(Motherboard: Gigabyte ex58-ud3r, CPU: i7 2.6 GHZ)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M-audio support responded, and said what this trouble directly related to the driver.
At the moment there is no official support for the audiophile and Windows 8.
So the solution is to wait until the new driver version will be released for windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with M-Audio cards on Win7, too. My Delta 66 has this same issue on Win 76 64 bit.

Users on the old M-audio forum (that was shut down) railed about this issue for a long time.

Just bad customer support.

I have searched for countless solutions. I have not found any suitable ones. The only "solution" is to go into task manager, stop audiosrv, then restart it.

Very annoying.